# How to trigger a method once all messages are consumed?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My code sends a batch of messages to multiple RabbitMQ Consumers and once the last message is consumed, I want to trigger a method. The timing to trigger the method **has to** to be after all messages because it uses data from all the message processing.

Is there a way to do that with `spring-amqp`?

Comment: Define "all messages consumed"... Is that because the MQ provider stopped sending messages? If yes, how do you detect that?

Comment: @fge I'm processing messages in "cycles", so I could potentially insert a dummy start and end messages into the queue. When the "end" message is processed, I want to wait until all other messages are processed then trigger the method. That's what I mean by "all messages consumed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming 1.6 release (currently 1.6.0.M1 - first milestone release) has a new feature to [emit application events when the container goes idle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#idle-containers).

With earlier versions you have to arm a timer (scheduled task) yourself and cancel then re-arm it whenever a message arrives.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can achieve it by using `spring-batch` and have a `AmqpWriter` in a `step` and would having my code inside `StepExecutionListener.afterStep()` guarantee it to be triggered after all messages are processed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `AmqpWriter` in this context; you could wrap a `RabbitTemplate` in an `ItemReader` and, when `receive()` returns `null` it would indicate the end of the step.